# Why does azure synapse create a SQL Server in version 12 when the features require version 14 or 16 or above?

Tags: sql-server, azure-synapse, workload

I am trying to work through a quickstart of Azure synapse analytics.  I created my own data warehouse with a SQL Server in a SQL pool with their `AdventureWorks` data.

Then I tried to create a workload group as they say to do in the quickstart, but it fails with this error:

> Statement 'CREATE WORKLOAD GROUP' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.

It turns out that the SQL Server is version 12. They don't let you control the version. That is what they create when you create the SQL pool. Not sure if it is related to using the Basic vs. higher level, but that just doesn't seem right.  Is there anything I can do about it?  I am trying to try out their features to demo it to a client.

Comment: What do you mean by *SQL Server is version 12* - are you talking about SQL Server **2012**, or do you mean SQL Server **2014** (which is **v12.x.y.z**) - please clarify !

Comment: I have never worked with Synapse before but encountered similar problems elsewhere. I am guessing the "template" for creating a pool is outdated, i.e. coded to create an old version of SQL Server. When creating a pool, you should have an ability to see/save an [ARM template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/overview). Have a look if SQL Server version is specified there and change it to a later one.

Comment: General observation: Azure products (likely same for other cloud providers but not sure) are a cobbled together bunch of somewhat integrated (often things you expect to work, just don't) products developed by separate teams. Even looking at tutorials and documentation, you can see they don't keep it up-to-date, often documents refer to old screenshots with outdated feature sets.

Comment: @user3058911 - Just curious if you have managed to resolve this issue and how you did it.